# How to get checked checkboxes from Kendo UI CheckBoxGroup

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I just started using the Kendo CheckBoxGroup and have no idea on how to get the checked checkedboxes, any ideas?

```js
$(document).ready((e) => {
  GenerateCheckBoxList();
});

function GenerateCheckBoxList() {
  const lst = ["A", "B", "C"];
  $("#RoomsCheckBoxList").kendoCheckBoxGroup({
    items: lst,
    layout: "vertical"
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/js/kendo.all.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.default-main.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.common-bootstrap.min.css" />
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://kendo.cdn.telerik.com/2022.3.913/styles/kendo.bootstrap.min.css" />

<ul id="RoomsCheckBoxList"></ul>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will return an array of all the items as html elements:

```
$("#RoomsCheckBoxList").getKendoCheckBoxGroup().items();
```

You can then look at the 'checked' property on each one.

https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/ui/checkboxgroup